racket JSON saving and loading passwords
I am trying to create a really simple gui in drRacket for a bank users. The users are supposed to create an account and then log in (even if they created their account, then closed the gui, and then ran it again to log in).
So there should be a way to store data sych as emails and passwords. Google told me that storing this in a JSON file is the best option, and then I can retrieve this data when comparing the passwords and emails, for example. I am not thinking about any encryption or anything, because I'm a newbie; for now I'm just trying to understand how it works and create something simple.
I tried creating a json file where the info would go, then a function to save the incoming data, and then another one to retrieve if when needed. Hovewer, this simple process is taking too long for me to follow and is becoming more and more complicated. It's been 3 days and pending for me to figure it out. I am asking for any kind of information on how to handle this task in Racket (even with something else, json is not a must). If there are any videos or books etc please share a link. Thank you!
#lang racket
(require racket/gui/base
         json)


(struct user (userID userType userName userEmail userPhone userPassword) #:mutable)
(define userAccount (make-hash))
(define user-id-counter (make-parameter 1))

(define (generate-user-id) 
  (define id (user-id-counter)) 
  (user-id-counter (add1 id)) 
  id)

(define (find-user email password)
  (let ((user (hash-ref userAccount email #f)))
    (if (and user (string=? (user-userPassword user) password))
        user
        #f)))

(define (save-users-to-file file-path)
  (with-output-to-file file-path
    #:exists 'truncate
    (lambda ()
      (write-json
       (map (lambda (entry)
              (user->json (cdr entry)))
            (hash->list userAccount))
       (current-output-port)))))

(define (user->json user)
  `(("userID" . ,(user-userID user))
    ("userType" . ,(user-userType user))
    ("userName" . ,(user-userName user))
    ("userEmail" . ,(user-userEmail user))
    ("userPhone" . ,(user-userPhone user))
    ("userPassword" . ,(user-userPassword user))))

(define (load-users-from-file file-path)
  (when (file-exists? file-path)
    (let* ((content (with-input-from-file file-path
                      (lambda ()
                        (port->string (current-input-port)))))
           (data (if (string-blank? content)
                     '()
                     (string->jsexpr content))))
      (when (list? data)
        (for-each
         (lambda (entry)
           (let ((user-data (json->user entry)))
             (hash-set! userAccount (user-userEmail user-data) user-data)))
         data)))))


(define (json->user json-data)
  (user
   (cdr (assoc "userID" json-data))
   (cdr (assoc "userType" json-data))
   (cdr (assoc "userName" json-data))
   (cdr (assoc "userEmail" json-data))
   (cdr (assoc "userPassword" json-data))))


(define (add-user! user)
  (hash-set! userAccount (user-userEmail user) user)
  (save-users-to-file "users.json"))

(load-users-from-file "users.json")

(define new-user (user "1" "band" "Band Name" "band@example.com" "123-456-7890" "password123"))

(add-user! new-user)

This is where I stopped at the moment, it doesn't run because of 'string-blank?'. My question being - am I moving in a right direction or is it a complete mess? What do I do?

string-blank? is not a Racket procedure. Did you intend to implement it but forgot?

@molbdnilo cuz i couldn't find any info on how to do it in general, i was trying to use my existing knowledge and implement it in racket, which looks, yeah, super weird... that's why i'm asking for any kind of info about how to do it properly :(

An actual database (like sqlite) would probably be a better option than a json file...

Or even using prefab struts and write/reading lists of them.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
